# android- Multiple list views in single screen

Tags: android, android-listview, uiscrollview

I wanna do like this UI in my app

[image]

Is it possible to do like this two list view in single layout? And one(left) is scrollable and another (right)one is not scrollable.

Comment: use fragments you can do it easily with fragments

Comment: yes whats problrm have u use muliitem listview

Comment: Please can you  provide a sample code or ref link for that?

Comment: Hope this links helps : http://www.nurne.com/2011/06/android-how-to-multiple-listviews-in_9533.html

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/05/android-working-with-fragments.html

Comment: @Siddharth Vyas Thanks for the reference...It helped me..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple **ListView** in single screen, ofcourse. Either you can use it directly by declaring in **XML** or you can do this using **Fragment**, create 2 different **Fragment** and use thatindividual **Fragments** with individual **ListViews**.